# PingFederate OpenToken Attribute Contract

Tags: pingfederate

I have a question regarding the Attribute Contract configuration of an OpenToken Adapter for an IdP Server. As I was trying out the sample applications, it already has a config provided with it. Now that I'm trying to configure it without using data.zip, I'm having problems.

As I was trying to create a new adapter, the core contract **subject** shows up automatically. I have no idea what are the default attributes included in this contract.

Question: How will I edit what are the contents of this contract? Will my IdP Application handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**subject** is the core contract, because that is what will carry the identity of the user, and is therefore the "minimum" - it must be returned (hence, "core"). Extended attributes can be added at the adapter, as long as the authentication method (such as a custom login page that retrieves attributes from a DB or something similar) can populate them into the token.

You may wish to review the documentation of the [OpenToken Adapter](https://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/PF73/OpenToken+Adapter+Configuration).

Comment: Yes, I get that the core contract is the "minimum" attributes needed. But can I edit what values should be included in that core contract? Or is that the default attributes? (for the sample app i see that it has 5: username, password, and 3 more information regarding the expiration of the token)

Comment: Just add any additional attributes that your adapter can provide to the extended contract.

Answer (score 0):

Within PingFederate, the IdP Adapters are essentially Authentication plug-ins.  There are many different types of IdP Adapters, whether it be the IWA IdP Adapter, HTML Form IdP Adapter, or the OpenToken IdP Adapter.  The main use of the OpenToken adapter is to create a custom authentication plug-in that is an application you would implement. This is normally done for organizations that have very custom requirements for authentication that the out-of-the-box HTML Form Adapter or IWA Adapter cannot meet. The PingFederate sample applications for IdP show how to implement the interface.

When you use the OpenToken adapter, it is a secure interface between the PingFederate IdP Server and a custom application using the OpenToken specification.  The custom application can be written in Java, .NET, or PHP and integrate using the OpenToken agent for the target programming language. As Andrew stated above, that custom application could query for attributes beyond simple authentication of the subject.  Then within the application when the OpenToken is being generated you would need to insert the additional fields into the OpenToken.  Then in the OpenToken Adapter hosted on the PingFederate you would need to configure the extended attributes using the matching syntax so that they could be used.